# How to specify webpack-dev-server webpack.config.js file location

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json

I am starting with webpack.

I have been able to specify to webpack the location of webpack.config.js like this:

```
"webpack --config ./App/webpack.config.js"
```

Now I am trying to use the webpack-dev-server with that file also, but I can not find how to specify the webpack.config.js location to it.

This is the relevant part of my package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./App/webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
  "build": "webpack --config ./App/webpack.config.js --progress --colors"
}
```

How can I pass the ./App/ directory to my webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Using `--config` should work. What error do you get?

Answer (score 52):

Just came across this issue. As spacek33z said, `--config` is correct. I couldn't find this in the webpack docs or the webpack-dev-server docs, so I found myself at this question.

e.g.

`webpack-dev-server --config demo/webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 16):

For newbies like me:

Mention the config path in package.json similar to below:

```
{
  "name": "abc",

  "version": "0.0.1",

  "description": "description",

  "main": "index.js",

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./client/webpack.config.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./client/webpack.config.js"
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a configuration file example? as webpack.config.js